# How can I allow allocation of storage to a harddrive?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, ntfs, storage

I have a computer with a 500 GB SSD (non m.2) that I boot Windows off of. It is connected to my motherboard via SATA 3 as well as a 1 TB hard drive. However, I can't seem to be able to access the hard drive in any capacity from Windows itself. I can see it in diskpart for some strange reason though:

```
DISKPART> list disk

  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online          465 GB  1024 KB        *
  Disk 1    Online          931 GB      0 B        *
```

As you can see it is `Disk 1` in diskpart. However, even if I use `sel disk 1` and `list vol` or anything, it outputs the same as it would for disk 0.

```
DISKPART> list disk

  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online          465 GB  1024 KB        *
  Disk 1    Online          931 GB      0 B        *

DISKPART> sel disk 1

Disk 1 is now the selected disk.

DISKPART> list vol

  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
  Volume 0     C                NTFS   Partition    465 GB  Healthy    Boot
  Volume 1                      NTFS   Partition    505 MB  Healthy
  Volume 2                      FAT32  Partition    100 MB  Healthy    System

DISKPART> sel disk 0

Disk 0 is now the selected disk.

DISKPART> list vol

  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
  Volume 0     C                NTFS   Partition    465 GB  Healthy    Boot
  Volume 1                      NTFS   Partition    505 MB  Healthy
  Volume 2                      FAT32  Partition    100 MB  Healthy    System

DISKPART>
```

I can also see the disk in `Devices and Printers` where I have the option to eject it.

How can I allocate/store any amount of storage or make use of this disk in any way whatsoever?

Motherboard/BIOS Aourus Latest BIOS I think?

Comment: What shows up in Disk Management?

Comment: If you go to disk management, you will probably see that you have not actually allocated it for storage. If you right click the unallocated drive, you'll be given the option to allocate it.

Comment: What do you get from `list part` instead?

Comment: `list vol` gives all volumes in the computer. Nothing to do with the selected disk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can allocate storage to a drive in **Disk Management**.

---

<sub>This is an extension of Jojomatiks answer just providing more detail.</sub>

---

**Ways to get to disk management**

- In Windows search, search for `Disk Management` or `Create and Format Hard Disk Partitions`
- Click <kbd>Win-R</kbd> to open the run dialog and type in compmgmt.msc and under `Storage`, Disk Management should be there. (You can also run compmgmt from the Windows search box or cmd)

---

The next step is to clean the disk so it becomes uninitialized, this is not required most of the time, but this is to make sure it works

1. Open diskpart with the `diskpart` cmd command or typing `diskpart` into the Windows search box
2. Use `List disk` to see the disks.
3. Find the disk you want and select the disk with `sel disk 1` or any other number
4. Run `clean` and wait for it to finish

This will wipe the disk so it becomes uninitialized and you should be able to see the change from Disk Management.

---

#### Initializing the disk and Allocating Storage

1. In the bottom of disk management, you should see your disks. Since we just uninitialized a disk, right-click the uninitialized disk you want (on the left-side where it has the disk number, storage, and whether it is uninitialized or online.
2. Under the right-click menu, select `Initialize disk` and when the popup appears select the disk you want and GPT (unless you want to make a Master Boot Record then select MBR)
3. Then right-click the right side with the disk space and partitions where it has the storage and "Unallocated." In the right-click menu, select `New Simple Volume...`
4. The *New Simple Volume Wizard* should pop up and click next.
5. In the next page, select the amount of storage you want your simple volume to be in MB. To utilize the whole thing, just put the same number as the `Maximum disk space in MB` and click next.
6. On the next page, choose your drive letter, whether you do or don't want to have a drive letter or if you want to mount the drive in the folder of the normal drive. Once you have chosen, click next.
7. Select whether or not you want to format the drive and what format options you want to pick. I suggest NTFS file system with quick format. Choose the volume label of the drive a well then click next.
8. Then on the next page click finish.

You will see the drive say `Formatting...` in disk management. Wait for it to finish, then you can use it like normal

Answer (score 2):

Since `list vol` only shows those 3 volumes I'd argue that **you need to create a volume** on the new (at least I assume its new) disk.

The easiest way to do this is opening up the **"Disk Management"** application and create a new volume there by **right clicking on the unallocated space** and then **clicking "new simple volume"**.